# How to get a clean environment in a ksh shell?

Tags: shell, environment-variables, ksh

I need to get rid of all the environment variables in a Ksh shell. I can fork a new instance, but it will inevitably source some init files (as far as I know `.profile`, `.kshrc`). Is there a way to bypass the sourcing of those files and any other file that might be read at init time?

- Ksh version: Version M-11/16/88i
- OS: Solaris 10

Hope I'm clear enough.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`~/.profile` is only read by login shells. `~/.kshrc` is only executed for interactive shells.

Solaris's `env` supports the syntax (now deprecated, but retained in Solaris, which takes backward compatibility seriously) `env - /path/to/command` to run `/path/to/command` in an empty environment. So `env - /usr/bin/ksh -c /path/to/script` will run the script in an empty environment and will not source any profile script. Ksh might set some environment variables on its own initiative: I don't know about ksh88, but ksh93 sets `_` and `PWD`, and pdksh sets `_` and `PATH`.

You can selectively or indiscriminately clear environment variables from inside ksh.

```
unset x
for x in $(typeset +x); do
  unset $x
done
```

Comment: `env - /path/to/command` is a standard compliant syntax, unless I misunderstand what you means.

Comment: @jlliagre It is? Oh, it [was](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7990989775/xcu/env.html) but now [it's been withdrawn in favor of `env -i`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/env.html).

Comment: @Gilles: As usual your explanations are perfect. Is there a way to publicly thank you for everything you've (directly and indirectly) taught me in the course of the past three months? :)

Comment: @rahmu Use your newfound knowledge or your knowledge of other topics to provide good answers to other people's questions. Or otherwise [make the Internet a better place](http://xkcd.com/386/). Or otherwise make the world a better place.

Answer (score 5):

```
me@local:~ $ env - /path/to/shell
$ env
_=/usr/bin/env
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin
RANDOM=24395
$
```

Notes:

- I used a shell to have a look at the resulting environment, any command can be used (guess what `env - /usr/bin/env` returns)
- (@jlliagre's comment:) `env` is a POSIX standard command.

**Edit** Clarified the answer.

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't find it on Solaris.

Comment: @rahmu According to the man pages (I don't have Solaris 10 to check), all versions of Solaris since at least 2.4 support `env -`. Run `/usr/bin/ksh` and not `mksh`, of course.

Comment: Indeed, `env` is a POSIX standard command so definitively in Solaris (including 10 and newer).

Comment: Oh I got mislead by the `mksh`. I thought it was an executable that "cleaned" the environment :-/ In this case, the answer seems correct.