# How to run a program in a clean environment in bash?

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I want to run a program in an empty environment (i.e. with no envariables set). How to do this in bash?

Comment: Possibly related: [How to get a clean environment in a ksh shell](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23822/how-to-get-a-clean-environment-in-a-ksh-shell)

Answer (score 195, accepted):

You can do this with `env`:

```
env -i your_command
```

Contrary to comments below, this *does* completely clear out the environment, but it does not prevent `your_command` setting new variables. In particular, running a shell will cause the `/etc/profile` to run, and the shell may have some built in settings also.

You can check this with:

```
env -i env
```

i.e. wipe the environment and then print it. The output will be blank.

Comment: It doesn't completely clear out the environment: `echo 'echo $PATH' > test.sh && chmod u+x test.sh && env -i test.sh` prints `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin`.

Comment: However, it seems this is the closest you can get - It seems like variables like `PATH`, `PWD` and `SHLVL` are set automatically by Bash. +1.

Comment: @I0b0: See my edit.

Comment: The PATH variable in the first commenter's script is not in the environment and therefore is not an environment variable.  Bash apparently sets its own regular shell variable called PATH if there isn't one exported for it:  `env -i bash --norc -c "declare -p PATH"`
gives `declare -- PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:."`.  Note the "-x" for exported (and therefore part of the environment) if you export it yourself: `env -i bash --norc -c "export PATH; declare -p PATH"`
gives `declare -x PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:."`

Answer (score 69):

A "clean" `bash` environment may be had with

```
$ env -i bash --noprofile --norc
```

- The `env -i` command executes the command given to it on the command line without transferring any of the exported environment variables of the old shell environment to the environment of the executed program.
- The `--noprofile` option stops `bash` from reading the system-wide or personal shell initialization scripts that would otherwise be read for a login shell.
- The `--norc` option stops `bash` from reading the personal shell initialization scripts that would otherwise be read for an interactive shell.

Comment: My env doesn't recognize those options.

Comment: @PauloCarvalho Your system does not support `env -i`? What system are you on?

Comment: Sorry, it works in the shell.  I tried to put it in a script and somehow it threw an error.

Comment: @PauloCarvalho Sorry, I can't see what command you typed in or what the error you got was.

Comment: Great - just what I was looking for. `env` to clean my environment, and `--noprofile` to avoid sourcing /etc/profile and friends, and `--norc` to avoid sourcing ~/.bashrc and friends.

Comment: In this case, even "standard" environment variables like `HOME` and `USER` are not set.  Is there a way to do this without losing those variables?

Answer (score 40):

`env -i somecommand` runs a command in an empty environment, as [ams has already mentioned](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48994/how-to-run-a-program-in-a-clean-environment-in-bash/48995#48995).

A lot of programs rely on some important environment variables, so you may want to retain them:

```
env -i HOME="$HOME" LC_CTYPE="${LC_ALL:-${LC_CTYPE:-$LANG}}" PATH="$PATH" USER="$USER" somecommand
```

Alternatively, you could log in into a small login-time environment.

```
ssh localhost somecommand
```

Comment: Works when running the command on cmdline. How do I put this in shebang?, doesn't seem to [work](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/98829)!

Comment: Strange, my `env` doesn't support `--` delimitation and doing `env -i FOO=bar -- env` attempts to run a command named `--`.

Comment: @antak That should be `env -i -- FOO=bar env`, actually. My bad. Not that the `--` is useful since what follows it does not start with `-`.

Comment: Didn't realize you could always ssh into localhost, that's kinda weird. What's the use case there.

Comment: @EdgarAroutiounian You can SSH to localhost if it's running an SSH server. Why would programmers go through the effort of forbidding it?

Comment: @EdgarAroutiounian an example use-case would be having a 'vanilla' environment set from the user's standard login environment, then within a script later being forced to make unknown changes to the running environment to accomodate required software (think system `module`s), then needing to return to the user's original environment. Instead of trying to parse `env`, it may be easier to just `ssh $USER@knownlocalhost somecommand`

Answer (score 9):

While the accepted answer is correct, what you usually want to do is to:

`env -i HOME="$HOME" bash -l -c "printenv; and any other commands"`

This gives you bare but functional bash (same as you'd get when login in non-interactive mode). This for example sets the language, timezone, HOME, etc.

Edit: Added `HOME="$HOME"` based on excellent answer here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/451389/100093

Comment: That doesn't quite work because `env -i` clears `HOME`, which means `bash -l` can't find your `.bash_profile` etc. If you want a shell that's like what you'd get on a fresh login, you need an extra indirection to set `HOME` first.

Comment: See this answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/451389/157340

Answer (score 6):

The problem with most answers here is that `env -i` clears `HOME`, so even if you run `bash -l` on the inside, it won't read your `.bash_profile` etc. If what you're looking for is a shell that acts as if you had just done a fresh login, you'd want this instead:

```
env -i HOME="$HOME" bash -l -c 'your_command'
```

Example:

```
$ export ABC=123
$ env -i HOME="$HOME" bash -l -c 'env' | grep ABC
$ env HOME="$HOME" bash -l -c 'env' | grep ABC
ABC=123
```

Comment: Note that a login `bash` shell will run `.bash_login` or `.bash_profile`.  To get a clean environment, use `--noprofile`, or set `HOME` to a directory that does not have those files. I suppose it depends on what you mean by "clean".

Comment: Yes, if you want a shell with literally nothing in it, just follow the original answer and do `env -i bash -c ...`. This answer is specifically when you want a shell that looks like you just did a fresh login on the machine.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to ensure a script has a clean environment you can alter the shebang line like this little example illustrates:

```
#!/usr/bin/env -S -i bash
env
```

which displays its environment like this

```
PWD=/home/myuser/mydir
SHLVL=1
_=/usr/bin/env
```

Here, we run the `bash` shell through `env` which takes an `-i` argument that instructs it to clean the environment. The `-S` is [required when passing multiple arguments on shebang lines](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/env.1.html).

Comment: This works on bash 5.0.3 on my Debian 10.4 box, but RHEL 7.7 uses 4.2.46(2)-release and it doesn't work the same on bash 4.

Answer (score 0):

To answer balki's comment (and answering my own question in the process :-):

```
% echo Environment in calling shell: vars: $(env |wc -l); echo; ./du; echo; cat du
Environment in calling shell: vars: 43

==> This is the environment: vars: 5
PATH="$PATH"
PWD=/Users/nick
SHLVL=1
SOMETHING_TO_KEEP="$USER"
_=/usr/bin/env
==> The end.

#!/usr/bin/env -i SOMETHING_TO_KEEP="$USER" PATH="$PATH" /bin/sh

echo "==> This is the environment: vars:" $(/usr/bin/env | /usr/bin/wc -l)
/usr/bin/env
echo "==> The end."
```

Comment: When I try this in my shebang line in CentOS 7.6, I get this error from env: `/usr/bin/env: invalid option -- ' '
Try '/usr/bin/env --help' for more information.
`

Comment: If I change the script to use the long argument `--ignore-environment` then I get this: `/usr/bin/env: unrecognized option '--ignore-environment SOMETHING_TO_KEEP="$USER" PATH="$PATH" /bin/sh'
Try '/usr/bin/env --help' for more information.
`