# How can I create a clean shell environment for temporary use?

Tags: bash, environment-variables, profile

I am a frequent answerer on a Unix-focused popular Q&A site, and in many of my answers I provide examples using the `bash` shell. However, each time I do this I have to manually go through the process of creating a clean environment to make sure that every step is accounted for and documented. How can I make this process more straightforward? I am ideally looking to type a single command and get a clean environment, and have all traces of that temporary environment removed after I am done.

Comment: related: [How to run a program in a clean environment in bash?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48994/how-to-run-a-program-in-a-clean-environment-in-bash)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I personally use the following `bash` function to do this:

```sh
so() {
    local tmpdir="$(mktemp -d)"
    local tmprc="$(mktemp)"
    cat > "$tmprc" << EOF
PS1='\\$ '
cd "$tmpdir"
EOF
    env - HOME="$HOME" TERM="$TERM" bash --rcfile "$tmprc"
    rm -rf "$tmpdir" "$tmprc"
}
```

Here is what it does, in order:

- Create a temporary directory (to use as our working directory in the clean environment);
- Create a temporary file (to use as our `bash` rc file);
- In the rc file, add lines which:

  - Set the `PS1` prompt to the prompt terminator followed by a space, which keeps it relevant in case we want to have a copy of our output on the Q&A site;
  - Change into the temporary directory we created.
- Invoke a new instance of `bash`, which:

  - Initially has an empty environment except for `$HOME` and `$TERM` (`env - ...`);
  - Reads its rc file from the temporary file we created earlier (`--rcfile`).
- Once bash has exited, remove the temporary files we created.

Obviously this is not totally foolproof, that is, you can still access other parts of your system. This does, however, provide a clean temporary environment which you can use for testing.

Comment: have you tried using `script`?

Answer (score 2):

`chroot` is one way, using a VM is another.
You could build up the chroot-environment on a LV, snapshot it, do your whatever and then revert to the snapshotted state.

Or - do the same with the VM (disk-snapshot) and revert all changes afterwards.

I usually do this with a freshly installed VM (using VirtualBox and kickstart or autoyast with PXE-boot).