# How to start a script with clean environment?

Tags: bash, shell-script, env

I tried the following but it doesn't seem to work:

```
$ cat script.sh
#!/bin/env -i /bin/sh

/bin/env
$ script.sh
/bin/env: invalid option -- ' '
Try `/bin/env --help' for more information.
```

Comment: Found similar questions but doesn't show how to do from shebang:
http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48994/how-to-run-a-program-in-a-clean-environment-in-bash?rq=1

Comment: You can't do it from shebang. The shebang can only accept one arg.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reason this does not work is because it sees `-i /bin/sh` as a single argument to `env`. Usually this would be 2 arguments, `-i` and `/bin/sh`. This is just a limitation of the shebang. No way around it.

---

However you can still perform this task, just a different way.

If you want this task to be performed by the script itself, and not have to do something like `env -i script.sh`, you can have the script re-exec itself.

```
#!/bin/sh
[ -z "$CLEANED" ] && exec /bin/env -i CLEANED=1 /bin/sh "$0" "$@"
```

This will cause the script to re-exec itself if the `CLEANED` environment variable isn't set. Then on re-exec, it sets the variable to make sure that it doesn't go into a loop.

Comment: `env` from the GNU coreutils now have an option `-S` to workaround issues similar to this one but not exactly the same. For example `#!/usr/bin/env -S perl -T`.

Comment: Just tried. It works for the original question as well. Just use `#!/usr/bin/env -S -i /bin/sh`. Be aware of portability issues.

Comment: You may use `[ -z "${CLEANED:-}" ]"` when `-u` is set in the shebang e.g `#!/bin/sh -eu`

Answer (score 4):

Run your script with `env -i`:

```
env -i script.sh
```

And the script as usual:

```
#!/bin/sh
# ... your code here
```

If you mean to run with a clean environment without explicitly say that when you run. Eduardo Ivanec gives some ideas in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9671213/1392758), you can recursively call your script with `exec` when the environment is not clean (e.g. $HOME is defined):

```
[ "$HOME" != "" ] && exec -c $0
```

Comment: Nice. Just don't do env -i bash like I did and then wonder why your env variables are still set (of course bash resources .bashrc and friends 8)

Answer (score 3):

With bash, you can do it like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

set -e
set -u

[ -v HOME ] && exec -c "$0" "$@"

# continue with the rest of the script
# e.g. print the cleaned environment:
export
```

The `set -e` and `set -u`  commands are not strictly necessary, but I include them to demonstrate that this approach doesn't rely on accessing unset variables (as e.g. `[ "$HOME" != "" ]` would) and is compatible with a `set -e` setting.

Testing the `HOME` variable should be safe because bash executes scripts in non-interactive mode, i.e. configuration files like `~/.bashrc` (where environment variables may be set) are not sourced during startup.

Example output:

```
declare -x OLDPWD
declare -x PWD="/home/juser"
declare -x SHLVL="1"
```

Answer (score 1):

> `$ cat script.sh`
>
> `#!/bin/env -i /bin/sh`

Sadly it won't work that way — Linux does consider `-i /bin/sh` as one argument to be passed to `env` (see [Shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29)).

Answer (score 1):

The Linux 2-argument shebang limitation (interpeter + single argument) is noted in most of the answers, but to say this cannot be done is incorrect — you just need to change to an interpreter that can do something useful with a single argument:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -we%ENV=();exec "/bin/sh " . join " ", map "'$_'", @ARGV;
# your sh script here
```

What this does is invoke `perl` with a one-liner script (`-e`) that clears `%ENV` (cheaper than `env -i`) and invokes `exec /bin/sh`, correctly quoting the arguments. Further `perl` logic can be added, if required (though not much on Linux since you're limited to `BINPRM_BUF_SIZE` characters, which is likely 128). There's a variation on that using `awk` [in this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/551025/31352) to the question [Multiple arguments in shebang](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/399690/31352)

Sadly, this is Linux specific, it will not work on a system which allows multiple shebang arguments :-/

`perl` processes this string as a single argument, so it's *not quoted* above as you would ordinarily do with `perl -e ...` from the command line (if you were to add quotes these are preserved, perl sees only a literal string, with warnings on it will complain about a useless constant).

Also note there's a slight change in behaviour when used this way, `@ARGV` normally contains only the arguments, and `$0` contains the script name, but with this shebang `$ARGV[0]` is the name of the script which makes creating the `exec()` arguments a little easier (and `$0` contains `-e`).

You can also solve this with an interpreter that "reprocesses" its command line (without an extra `-c` argument) the ancient AT&T `ksh93` does:

```
#!/bin/ksh /usr/bin/env -i /bin/sh
```

though perhaps `ksh` isn't as common nowadays ;-)

(`bash` has a similar feature with `--wordexp`, *but* it's "undocumented" in the versions where it works, and not enabled at compile time in the versions where it is documented :-/ It also can't be used for this since it needs two arguments...)

Also, effectively a variation on @Patrick and @maxschlepzig's answers:

```
#!/bin/bash
[ "$_" != bash ] && exec -c -a "bash" /bin/bash "$0" "$@"
# your script here
```

Rather than use a new variable this uses the special "`_`" variable, if it's not set to exactly "bash" then replace the script with `exec` using `-a` to make `ARGV[0]` (and hence `$_`) just "bash", and using `-c` to clear the environment.

Alternatively, if it is acceptable to clean the environment at at the start of the script (bash only):

```
#!/bin/sh
unset $(compgen -e)
# your script here
```

That uses `compgen` (completion helper) to list the names of all the exported environment variables, and `unset`s them in one go.

See also [Multiple arguments in shebang](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399690/multiple-arguments-in-shebang) for more details on the general problem of shebang behaviour.