# Multiple arguments in shebang

Tags: scripting, environment-variables, posix, arguments, shebang

I am wondering whether there is a general way of passing multiple options to an executable via the shebang line (`#!`).

I use NixOS, and the first part of the shebang in any script I write is usually `/usr/bin/env`. The problem I encounter then is that everything that comes after is interpreted as a single file or directory by the system.

Suppose, for example, that I want to write a script to be executed by `bash` in posix mode. The naive way of writing the shebang would be:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash --posix
```

but trying to execute the resulting script produces the following error:

```
/usr/bin/env: ‘bash --posix’: No such file or directory
```

I am aware of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4303128/how-to-use-multiple-arguments-for-awk-with-a-shebang-i-e), but I was wondering whether there was a more general and cleaner solution.

---

**EDIT**: I know that for [Guile](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/) scripts, there is a way to achieve what I want, documented in [Section 4.3.4](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/html_node/Scripting-Examples.html) of the manual:

```
 #!/usr/bin/env sh
 exec guile -l fact -e '(@ (fac) main)' -s "$0" "$@"
 !#
```

The trick, here, is that the second line (starting with `exec`) is interpreted as code by `sh` but, being in the `#!` ... `!#` block, as a comment, and thus ignored, by the Guile interpreter.

Would it not be possible to generalize this method to any interpreter?

---

**Second EDIT**: After playing around a little bit, it seems that, for interpreters that can read their input from `stdin`, the following method would work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
sed '1,2d' "$0" | bash --verbose --posix /dev/stdin; exit;
```

It's probably not optimal, though, as the `sh` process lives until the interpreter has finished its job. Any feedback or suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63979/shebang-line-with-usr-bin-env-command-argument-fails-on-linux

Comment: Also relevant: [How to pass arguments to the shebang interpreter when executing a script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/182227/86440).

Comment: Use `#!/bin/sh -` instead of `#!/usr/bin/env sh`. `#!/bin/sh -` is *the* most portable hashbang line. `/bin/sh` is more likely to exist than `/usr/bin/env`. Only use `#!/usr/bin/env foo` is for every `foo` that is not `sh`.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

There is no general solution, at least not if you need to support Linux, because [the Linux kernel treats everything following the first “word” in the shebang line as a single argument](https://lwn.net/Articles/630727/).

I’m not sure what NixOS’s constraints are, but typically I would just write your shebang as

```
#!/bin/bash --posix
```

or, where possible, [set options in the script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/182227/86440):

```
set -o posix
```

Alternatively, you can have the script restart itself with the appropriate shell invocation:

```
#!/bin/sh -

if [ "$1" != "--really" ]; then exec bash --posix -- "$0" --really "$@"; fi

shift

# Processing continues
```

This approach can be generalised to other languages, as long as you find a way for the first couple of lines (which are interpreted by the shell) to be ignored by the target language.

GNU `coreutils`’ `env` provides a workaround since version 8.30, see [unode](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/4781/unode)’s [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/477651/86440) for details. (This is available in Debian 10 and later, RHEL 8 and later, Ubuntu 19.04 and later, etc.)

Comment: This circumvents the problem instead of solving it.

Comment: @Szczepan if you have a way to solve the problem, feel free to write your own answer.

Answer (score 100):

Although not exactly portable, starting with coreutils 8.30 and [according to its documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/env-invocation.html#g_t_002dS_002f_002d_002dsplit_002dstring-usage-in-scripts) you will be able to use:

```
#!/usr/bin/env -S command arg1 arg2 ...
```

So given:

```
$ cat test.sh
#!/usr/bin/env -S showargs here 'is another' long arg -e "this and that " too
```

you will get:

```
% ./test.sh 
$0 is '/usr/local/bin/showargs'
$1 is 'here'
$2 is 'is another'
$3 is 'long'
$4 is 'arg'
$5 is '-e'
$6 is 'this and that '
$7 is 'too'
$8 is './test.sh'
```

and in case you are curious `showargs` is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
echo "\$0 is '$0'"

i=1
for arg in "$@"; do
    echo "\$$i is '$arg'"
    i=$((i+1))
done
```

Comment: This is very good to know for future reference.

Comment: That option was copied from FreeBSD's `env` where `-S` was added in 2005. See https://lists.gnu.org/r/coreutils/2018-04/msg00011.html

Comment: Works a treat on Fedora 29

Comment: @unode some improvements of `showargs`: https://pastebin.com/q9m6xr8H and https://pastebin.com/gS8AQ5WA (one-liner)

Comment: FYI: as of coreutils 8.31, `env` includes its own `showargs`: [the -v option](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/env-invocation.html#Testing-and-troubleshooting) e.g. `#!/usr/bin/env -vS --option1 --option2 ...`

Comment: doesnt work on ubuntu 18.04.3

Comment: @Kokizzu The first series of Ubuntu to include coreutils 8.30 is 19.04. That's why it doesn't work on 18.04.

Comment: Is there a way to extend these `-S` arguments across multiple lines?

Comment: What if the executed file is under a directory with spaces in its name?

Comment: Oh, so the `env` parameter supposed to be `-S` and not `-v`… Thank you, that's a pretty bad error message they have in `env`, because the message clearly says you have to pass some variant of `env -v STRING`, for which I tried every combination imaginable only to find out here that `-v` is completely unrelated 

Answer (score 16):

The POSIX standard is very terse on describing `#!`:

From the [rationale section of the documentation of the `exec()` family of system interfaces](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/functions/execvp.html):

> Another way that some historical implementations handle shell scripts is by recognizing the first two bytes of the file as the character string `#!` and using the remainder of the first line of the file as the name of the command interpreter to execute.

From the [Shell Introduction section](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_01):

> The shell reads its input from a file (see `sh`), from the `-c` option or from the `system()` and `popen()` functions defined in the System Interfaces volume of POSIX.1-2008. **If the first line of a file of shell commands starts with the characters `#!`, the results are unspecified**.

This basically means that any implementation (the Unix you are using) is free to do the specifics of the parsing of the shebang line as it wants.

Some Unices, like macOS (can't test ATM), will split the arguments given to the interpreter on the shebang line into separate arguments, while Linux and most other Unices will give the arguments as a single option to the interpreter.

It is thus unwise to rely on the shebang line being able to take more than a single argument.

See also the [Portability section of the Shebang article on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)#Portability).

---

One easy solution, which is generalizable to any utility or language, is to make a wrapper script that executes the real script with the appropriate command line arguments:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec /bin/bash --posix /some/path/realscript "$@"
```

I don't think I would personally try to make it re-execute *itself* as that feels somewhat fragile.

Answer (score 12):

I found a rather stupid workaround when looking for an executable that accepts a script as a single argument:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk BEGIN{system("bash --posix "ARGV[1])}
```

Comment: If it works when no other sane solutions do - it's not stupid. It's a working solution.
Thank you. Worked perfectly for my Dockerfile

Answer (score 8):

The shebang is described in [`execve`(2)](https://linux.die.net/man/2/execve) man page as follow:

```
#! interpreter [optional-arg]
```

Two spaces are accepted in this syntax:

1. One space before the *interpreter* path, but this space is optional.
2. One space separating the the *interpreter* path and its optional argument.

Note that I didn't used the plural when talking of an optional argument, neither does the syntax above uses `[optional-arg ...]`, as *you can provide at most one single argument*.

As far as shell scripting is concerned, you can use the `set` built-in command near the beginning of your script which will allow to set interpreters parameters, providing the same result as if you used command-line arguments.

In your case:

```
set -o posix
```

From a Bash prompt, check the output of `help set` to get all available options.

Comment: You’re allowed to have more than two spaces, they’re just considered to be part of the optional argument.

Comment: @StephenKitt: Indeed, white space here is to be taken more as a category than the actual space char. I suppose that other white spaces such as tabs should also be widely accepted.

Answer (score 4):

On Linux, the shebang isn't very flexible; according to multiple answers ([Stephen Kitt's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/399698/57494) and [Jörg W Mittag's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4304187/2514354)), there is no designated way to pass multiple arguments in a shebang line.

I'm not sure if it will be of use to anyone, but I've written a short script to implement the lacking feature. See https://gist.github.com/loxaxs/7cbe84aed1c38cf18f70d8427bed1efa.

It is also possible to write embedded workarounds. Bellow, I present four **language-agnostic** workarounds applied to the same test script and the result each prints. I suppose that the script is executable and is in `/tmp/shebang`.

---

#### Wrapping your script in a bash heredoc inside process substitution

As far as I know, this is the most reliable language-agnostic way of doing it. It allows passing arguments and preserves stdin. The drawback is that the interpreter doesn't know the (real) location of the file it reads.

```
#!/bin/bash
exec python3 -O <(cat << 'EOWRAPPER'
print("PYTHON_SCRIPT_BEGINNING")

from sys import argv
try:
    print("input() 0 ::", input())
    print("input() 1 ::", input())
except EOFError:
    print("input() caused EOFError")
print("argv[0]   ::", argv[0])
print("argv[1:]  ::", argv[1:])
print("__debug__ ::", __debug__)
# The -O option changes __debug__ to False

print("PYTHON_SCRIPT_END")
EOWRAPPER
) "$@"
```

Calling `echo -e 'aa\nbb' | /tmp/shebang 'arg1' 'arg2 contains spaces' 'arg3\ uses\ \\escapes\\'` prints:

```
PYTHON_SCRIPT_BEGINNING
input() 0 :: aa
input() 1 :: bb
argv[0]   :: /dev/fd/62
argv[1:]  :: ['arg1', 'arg2 contains spaces', 'arg3\\ uses\\ \\\\escapes\\\\']
__debug__ :: False
PYTHON_SCRIPT_END
```

Note that process substitution produces a special file. This may not suit all executables. For instance, `#!/usr/bin/less` complains: `/dev/fd/63 is not a regular file (use -f to see it)`

I don't know if it is possible to have heredoc inside process substitution in dash.

---

#### Wrapping your script in a simple heredoc

Shorter and simpler, but you won't be able to access `stdin` from your script and it requires the interpreter to be able to read and execute a script from `stdin`.

```
#!/bin/sh
exec python3 - "$@" << 'EOWRAPPER'
print("PYTHON_SCRIPT_BEGINNING")

from sys import argv

try:
    print("input() 0 ::", input())
    print("input() 1 ::", input())
except EOFError:
    print("input() caused EOFError")
print("argv[0]   ::", argv[0])
print("argv[1:]  ::", argv[1:])
print("__debug__ ::", __debug__)
# The -O option changes __debug__ to False

print("PYTHON_SCRIPT_END")
EOWRAPPER
```

Calling `echo -e 'aa\nbb' | /tmp/shebang 'arg1' 'arg2 contains spaces' 'arg3\ uses\ \\escapes\\'` prints:

```
PYTHON_SCRIPT_BEGINNING
input() caused EOFError
argv[0]   :: -
argv[1:]  :: ['arg1', 'arg2 contains spaces', 'arg3\\ uses\\ \\\\escapes\\\\']
__debug__ :: True
PYTHON_SCRIPT_END
```

---

#### Use awk `system()` call but without arguments

Correctly passes the name of the executed file, but your script won't receive the arguments you give it.
Note that awk is the only language I know whose interpreter both is installed on linux by default and reads its instructions from the command line by default.

```
#!/usr/bin/gawk BEGIN {system("python3 -O " ARGV[1])}
print("PYTHON_SCRIPT_BEGINNING")

from sys import argv

print("input() 0 ::", input())
print("input() 1 ::", input())
print("argv[0]   ::", argv[0])
print("argv[1:]  ::", argv[1:])
print("__debug__ ::", __debug__)
# The -O option changes __debug__ to False

print("PYTHON_SCRIPT_END")
```

Calling `echo -e 'aa\nbb' | /tmp/shebang 'arg1' 'arg2 contains spaces' 'arg3\ uses\ \\escapes\\'` prints:

```
PYTHON_SCRIPT_BEGINNING
input() 0 :: aa
input() 1 :: bb
argv[0]   :: /tmp/shebang
argv[1:]  :: []
__debug__ :: False
PYTHON_SCRIPT_END
```

---

#### Use awk 4.1+ `system()` call, provided your arguments do not contain spaces

Nice, but only if you are sure your script won't be called with arguments containing spaces. As you can see, your arguments containing spaces would be split, unless the spaces are escaped.

```
#!/usr/bin/gawk @include "join"; BEGIN {system("python3 -O " join(ARGV, 1, ARGC, " "))}
print("PYTHON_SCRIPT_BEGINNING")

from sys import argv

print("input() 0 ::", input())
print("input() 1 ::", input())
print("argv[0]   ::", argv[0])
print("argv[1:]  ::", argv[1:])
print("__debug__ ::", __debug__)
# The -O option changes __debug__ to False

print("PYTHON_SCRIPT_END")
```

Calling `echo -e 'aa\nbb' | /tmp/shebang 'arg1' 'arg2 contains spaces' 'arg3\ uses\ \\escapes\\'` prints:

```
PYTHON_SCRIPT_BEGINNING
input() 0 :: aa
input() 1 :: bb
argv[0]   :: /tmp/shebang
argv[1:]  :: ['arg1', 'arg2', 'contains', 'spaces', 'arg3 uses \\escapes\\']
__debug__ :: False
PYTHON_SCRIPT_END
```

For awk versions below 4.1, you will have to use string concatenation inside a for loop, see example function https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Join-Function.html .

Comment: Quote the here document terminator to inhibit `$variable` or `\`command\`` substitution: `exec python3 -O <(cat <<'EOWRAPPER'`

Answer (score 2):

A trick to use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` with python on the `#!` (shebang) line that doesn't depend on anything else than the shell and works a treat:

```
#!/bin/sh
'''' 2>/dev/null; exec /usr/bin/env LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. python -x "$0" "$@" #'''

__doc__ = 'A great module docstring'
```

As explained elsewhere in this page some shells like `sh` can take a script on their standard input.

The script we give `sh` tries to execute the command `''''` which is simplified to `''` (the empty string) by `sh` and of course it fails to execute it as there are no `''` command, so it normally outputs `line 2: command not found` on the standard error descriptor but we redirect this message using `2>/dev/null` to the closest black hole because it'd be messy and confusing to the user to let `sh` display it.

We then proceed to the command of interest to us: `exec` which replaces the current shell process by what follows, in our case: `/usr/bin/env python` with the adequate parameters:

- `"$0"` to let python know which script it should open and interpret, and also set `sys.argv[0]`
- `"$@"` to set python's `sys.argv[1:]` to the arguments passed on the script command line.

And we also ask `env` to  set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable, which is the sole point of the hack.

The shell command ends at the comment starting with `#` so that the shell ignores the trailing triple quotes `'''`.

`sh` is then replaced by a shinny new instance of the python interpreter which open and read the python source script given as first argument (the `"$0"`).

Python opens the file and skips over the 1st line of the source thanks to the `-x` argument. *Note: it also works without `-x` because for Python a shebang is just a comment*.

Python then interprets the 2nd line as the docstring for the current module file, so if you need a valid module docstring, just set `__doc__` first thing in your python program as in the example above.

Comment: Related (similar): [How does this shebang that starts with a double hyphen (--) work?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/488068)

Comment: Given that an empty string is … um … empty, you should be able to drop your command not found monkey business: `''''exec ...` should get the job done. Note no space before exec or it will make it look for the empty command. You want to splice the empty onto the first arg so the so `$0` is `exec`.

Answer (score 0):

Coming a little late to this question but I had the issue that I wanted multiple arguments to my command, and also to pass command line args from the shebang invocation to the interpreter.

I put together this awk script:

```c
#!/usr/bin/awk BEGIN{ for (x = 1; x < ARGC; x++) {args=args sprintf("\"%s\" ", ARGV[x]); ARGV[i]=""} cmd = "COMMAND_HERE WITH_ARGS" args; system(cmd)}
```

Which allows me to execute the script as `./script 1 2`, and my command will be executed with the hardcoded args followed by the args the script was invoked with. This will give the script the name it is invoked with in COMMAND_HERE as the first arg, and the name that you invoked the script with in the second (If you don't want this, change the starting index in the for to 2), and not split quoted arguments containing spaces (If you want to split them, remove the escaped quotes around `%s` in the `sprintf()` call). This will also work with redirection and piping. I believe this is portable as it only uses basic builtin Awk features.

Comment: A script that runs an arbitrary command is a bit dangerous.

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding what you mean here, It won't run an arbitrary command, only the one specified in "COMMAND_HERE". Anything specified as a parameter is interpreted as an argument so can't be used to inject arbitrary commands (As far as I know, I did do some testing for this). If you object to the use of awk to run an arbitrary command, you can do the same with shebangs in general, admittedly, this is harder to read, but that's just a necessity of working around the limitations of shebangs.

Comment: Yes - my mistake.

Comment: I recommend against anything more complex than `#!/bin/bash`, `#!/bin/env bash`, or similar as a shebang. If you need to do more complex processing or argument/parameter processing, do it in the body of the script, not the shebang. Reasons for my recommendation include things like: 1) shebang lines may be limited or truncated, 2) some shebangs can be accidentally or intentionally broken by certain arguments, 3) during the shebang evaluation part, the environment may not be fully set up as needed, and other reasons, too long or many to post in a comment.