# Invalid option name error with shebang "#!/bin/bash -o pipefail" in script

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, shebang

I have a file named test.sh:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash -o pipefail
echo "Running test"
git diff HEAD^ HEAD -M --summary |
grep delete | 
cut --delimiter=' ' -f 5
```

When I try to run this script as:

```bsh
./test.sh
```

I get:

```bsh
/bin/bash: line 0: /bin/bash: ./test: invalid option name
```

I ran `cat -v test.sh` to check if there are carriage returns or anything, but that doesn't seem to be the case. I can run the script if I just run it as `bash test.sh`. Grateful for any help, and lmk if I can provide more info!

Comment: You can pass a single argument in the shebang, and you're trying to pass it two (-o and pipefail). I don't know of any system where that (still) works.

Comment: If this is linux, check your execve man page.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Linux kernel treats everything following the first “word” in the shebang line [as a single argument](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/399698/29867). One solution is to `set -o` later in the script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

set -o pipefail

echo "Running test"
git diff HEAD^ HEAD -M --summary | grep delete | cut --delimiter=' ' -f 5
```