# How to use flags on appplication that use env?

Tags: shell-script, environment-variables

I'm using `env` in a shell script like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
...
...
```

Mainly so my scripts are more portable. Anyway, i noticed that adding arguments to application that use `env` doesn't always work...

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash -x
...
...
```

yield

```
/usr/bin/env: ‘bash -x’: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/env: use -[v]S to pass options in shebang lines
```

I'm unsure on the correct formatting for the arguments. I checked the man page and i didn't see anything that would help either (afaik).

Comment: Related: [Multiple arguments in shebang](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399690/multiple-arguments-in-shebang), in particular [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/477651/65304)

Comment: Interesting. I didn't found this when i searched on Unix.SE search engine... @steeldriver

Comment: Yeah, it does...but i already answered it with a similar answer, prior to finding such post(since i didn't found other post that had the solution, like the one you posted). @StephenKitt Should i delete this post, wait 2 days to accept my own answer or accept the linked post you provided?

Comment: I’d recommend accepting the dupe. You can still leave your answer if you feel it adds more information. Keeping your question helps make the other question easier to find.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems using the `-S` flag on `env`, like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/env -S bash -x
...
...
```

works.

It is interesting to note that, for some reasons, it is not stated in the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/env), though, it is shown in the `--help` output.

Probably has to do with the fact that `env` only started to have the `-S` flag when coreutils got updated (to `8.30`). I'm guessing most man page aren't updated and still have information from before `8.30` (eg: `8.28` didn't have the `-S` flag).

reference:

https://jhermann.github.io/blog/linux/know-how/2020/02/28/env_with_arguments.html
https://linux.die.net/man/1/env

Comment: The man page link is 10 years out of date.

Comment: I didn't check other man pages, but most (that are online) aren't kept up to date... @rowboat

Comment: Michael Kerrisk’s site is kept up-to-date, that’s one of the better references for manpages — see [`env`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/env.1.html). The best reference is usually `man env` on the target system since that will match the installed command.

Comment: yeah, forgot to check man7.org :D. Also, i asked mainly because i sometimes don't have `man` installed (eg: working on embedded systems). @StephenKitt

Comment: And for GNU software the best reference is the full manual for the corresponding project; see [the section on `env -S`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/env-invocation.html#g_t_002dS_002f_002d_002dsplit_002dstring-usage-in-scripts).

Comment: Right, embedded systems are another kettle of fish, since they might use other variants of commands (*e.g.* Busybox) which don’t always have the same options.