# #!/usr/bin/env hangs with NAME=VALUE

Tags: shell, environment-variables, shebang

I'm trying to figure out exactly what the semantics of the shebang are.

I can write a script like this:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [ -z "$FOO" ]
then
    echo "No FOO"
else
    echo "$FOO"
fi
```

without `$FOO` in my environment, and run it like `./foo.sh`, `bash foo.sh`, `env bash foo.sh`, etc and it will print "No FOO" as expected.

I can of course run it like `FOO=bar ./foo.sh` and it will print `bar`.

The `env` man page gives the invocation as:

```
env [OPTION]... [-] [NAME=VALUE]... [COMMAND [ARG]...]
```

And I can use it as such:

```
$ env FOO=bar bash foo.sh
bar
```

However, if I try to use that syntax in a shebang:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env FOO=bar bash

if [ -z "$FOO" ]
then
    echo "No FOO"
else
    echo "$FOO"
fi
```

then `./foo.sh` hangs indefinitely and does not execute.

Can someone explain this to me? I assumed that when a shebang is encountered, it just copies the command, appends the path to the script to the end of the argument list, and executes it, but this behavior suggests otherwise.

Comment: Which bash version are you using?

Comment: Perhaps related: [Multiple arguments in shebang](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399690/multiple-arguments-in-shebang)

Comment: GNU bash 5.0.17(1)-release

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most systems accept only up to **one** argument after the path of the interpreter in the shebang line. If you provide more than one, [the behaviour depends on the system](https://www.in-ulm.de/%7Emascheck/various/shebang/#results).

On Linux, all of what's after the interpreter (without leading and trailing space or tab characters) is passed as a single argument. So with a she-bang of:

```
#! /usr/bin/env FOO=bar bash
```

The system will call `/usr/bin/env` with `FOO=bar bash` and `/path/to/the/script` as arguments. Then `env` will run the script again with `FOO=bar bash` in its environment, and not `bash` with `/path/to/the/script` as argument (and `FOO=bar` in the environment), causing an infinite loop.

Some implementations of `env`, including FreeBSD's and recent versions of GNU `env`, can be told to do the splitting themselves  with `-S` to work around that limitation.

In

```
#! /usr/bin/env -S FOO=bar bash
```

A `"-S FOO=bar bash"` single argument will still be passed to `env`, but `env` will split the `" FOO=bar bash"` argument of that `-S` option and will behave as if called with `FOO=bar` and `bash` as separate arguments.

See the [GNU `env` manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/env-invocation.html#g_t_002dS_002f_002d_002dsplit_002dstring-usage-in-scripts) or [FreeBSD `env` manual](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=env&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%2013.0-RELEASE%20and%20Ports&arch=default&format=html) for details as to how the splitting is done.