# Can bash script reset & sanitize *whole* environment and how?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, security, environment-variables

You know this `sudo` stuff:

`Defaults    env_reset`

which makes environment injection impossible. **I was wandering if this functionality can be obtained from bash script directly, 'from inside'?**

At least part of it can, that is for sure. Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
//...

// sanitizes $PATH
putenv("PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"); 

// unsets $LD_LIBRARY_PATH, as it should be in Ubuntu
putenv('LD_LIBRARY_PATH');
//...
```

Can we do `env_reset` in running script like `sudo` does and how?

> EDIT:
>
> I'm not looking for the way to do it 'from outside' like `env -i
>   command` but from inside of script itself. My intention is to ensure
>   security no matter who (what user) and how(under which circumstances,
>   i.e. env variables) runs it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run a program in a clean environment in bash?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48994/how-to-run-a-program-in-a-clean-environment-in-bash)

Comment: @Kusalananda why duplicate? I'm not after empty environment nor the way to do it 'from outside' like `env -i`.

Comment: the php script might be a little distracting, if you're asking about bash; the syntax for clearing an environment will differ among scripting languages.  For reference, [sudo's environment handling](https://www.sudo.ws/repos/sudo/file/tip/plugins/sudoers/env.c)

Comment: What are the security concerns? If you want to be sure of getting a clean environment, then `env -i bash --norc --noprofile` will give you that. Apart from that, just list the environment variables and `unset` them, one by one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`bash` itself uses some environment variables. By the time `bash` is started and ready to interpret its first command, it's already too late, a malicious environment can have had `bash` do damage already.

You need the environment to have been sanitized before `bash` is called. You can wipe the environment  with the `clearenv()` C function on most systems or you could just call `execve()` on your script and pass an empty list in the `envp` parameter.

Even with a script that contains:

```
#! /bin/bash -
:
```

(`:` being a special builtin), if the environment contains `SHELLOPTS=xtrace PS4='$(reboot)'`, the `reboot` command will be invoked upon `:`.

If `bash` is dynamically linked, `LD_PRELOAD`/`LD_LIBRARY_PATH` can make `bash` run arbitrary code as soon as it's invoked.

`bash` also honours the locale's charset for its parsing, so with `LOCPATH` and `LC_*` variables, you can have even the `#! /bin/bash -` line invoke arbitrary code (by making `#!/bina` characters blanks for instance).

See also:

```
env SHELLOPTS=noexec any-bash-script
```

That stops `bash` from doing anything.

Those are just a few examples.

Also note that the environment variables are not the only things that a command inherits on startup and that may affect its behaviour (like arguments, umask, limits, current working directory, open file descriptors, signal disposition, controlling terminal...).

Answer (score 1):

You can find your exports with `export -p` or simply `export`, and replace the `declare -x` with `declare +x` on each line to unexport it:

```
eval "$(export|sed s/-/+/)"
```

If you put this at the beginning of your script, then no environment variables will be passed through to the programs it executes unless you explicitly export them yourself.  You'll probably want to export locale and `TZ` variables, and `TERM`, and more...

Comment: No, even `eval "$(export)"` is an arbitrary command injection vulnerability. Try `env -i '$(reboot)=x' bash -c export` for instance.

Comment: That part was fixed in bash-4.4 though.

Comment: My bash correctly quotes its `declare -x` output, so that's not an issue.  I do like the `PS4` attack in your answer, @Stéphane - very clever!